# Using a JIRA saved filter with REST API and Excel

Tags: excel, vba, rest, jira, jql

I have a report that I need to update in Excel many times a day using statistics from JIRA. If I can import these directly with code I would save a lot of time and effort.

Is it possible to use a saved JIRA filter in conjunction with the REST API function to import the results to Excel using a VBA macro?

Comment: Can't you use export issues option for this?

Comment: Yes. But if there is a way using a coded option that allows me to import the data without coming out of Excel. I would prefer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution does not use REST API, but it may work for you. This is a workaround I am using so far and it works:

1. Run the Filter in Jira
2. Export the result list into an excel file using the Export CSV file with the option current field (to avoid having unnecessary fields) and with the right button of mouse select: Open in a new window
3. Now you will see the URL associated with your filter in a new window of your browser. Your filter is represented by a Filter ID, therefore the query will be always the same.
4. Go to excel and use the URL as a hyperlink
5. Every time you click on the hyperlink it will download the file from Jira. You need to have a Jira open sesion in your browser.
6. Create a VBA marco that click on the hyperlink for downloading the file.
7. Use Power Query for example for loading the file from the download folder location into a worksheet. Power Query is a new excel feature. Power Query is an ETL tool integrated into excel for loading files and processing them.

The steps 6-7 automates the process. Run the Marco for downloading the file and refresh the content of your worksheet from Data Connection. You can have an additional macro that refreshes the content of the worksheet. It refreshes all pivot tables and the file connection for reading the file.

Hint: Use excel Table for keeping the information updated automatically when additional information is loaded into the worksheet. If you use pivot tables for presenting the data, use as data source an excel table instead of excel range.

It minimizes a lot the manual effort.

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088523/Excel-Jira-Rest-API-end-to-end-example) you can find a solution that uses REST API, the author provides the source code, but it is more complicated. If you need something simple, my solution may work for you.